# Error :NULL value is eliminated by aggregate or other set of operation in delphi7

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2008-r2, delphi-7

I am working on Delphi 7, SQL Server 2008 R2 project.

We are migrating from BDE to ADO. In ADO while posting data(TADOQuery.Post) We are getting below error and the values are getting saved into database.

[image]

How to avoid above error?

Comment: The error is from SQL Server, not Delphi https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/02/13/sql-server-warning-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-other-set-operation/

Comment: @GerryColl : it is sql error but when i am running it using TQuery(BDE), It is not throwing error and record is not saving.

Comment: @MartynA: there is no aggregate column in my ADO query. it is just simple select statement. and i am using dataware controls.

Comment: Then I suggest you add to your q the DDL SQL for the table you are using and the SQL your ADO query is using.  Btw, it is a table you are using and not a view, correct?

Comment: @MartynA : yes i am running this query on a table.

Comment: Pity you did not make the additions I suggested to your q, because now it has been marked as a duplicate, no-one can post an answer to it.  If you are still stuck, I suggest post a new q including the two SQL items I mentioned **and** the complete source code of a minimal Delphi project which exhibits the problem.  Btw can you reproduce the problem using the MS Sql Server "pubs" demo database?

Comment: It really isn't a Delphi question until there's some Delphi present. If you want to beef up the question so that it has a solid MCVE, that focuses on how you are tackling the SQL issue, then it can easily be reopened.

Comment: Please note what @DavidHeffernan says.  The point is, that error should not arise if you are doing a simple "select * from sometable", so readers need to be able to reproduce it and to do that, they need to see exactly how the table is defined and how you are getting data from it